Children's book about overconfident man who fights a bull
I read this book in elementary school about a man who was so strong that it made him arrogant and he believed he couldn't be beaten. At one point he even fights a bull and wins. He goes to the top of a mountain and yells out a challenge to the world asking if there is anyone capable of beating him. He then hears a voice call back to him saying "Skin for Skin".
I don't remember much after that but I believe that he finds himself in a challenge that he didn't even know he was in and he loses. It ends with him riding across the night sky on a bull with a small devil-like creature sitting behind him, and it is revealed that he swapped bodies with it so he is the devil creature while the devil is in his body.
Obviously it's about overconfidence.
I tried googling it but all I found were children's books about race. And this was before most of those books were written.
This would have been between 1997 and 2001.
